# How to run TestNG with command line

Tags: selenium, command-line, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am running Test cases in Selenium with **TestNG** framework. Through eclipse I can run all xml together, but how can I run it by command line or bat file.

I have tried with

```
start java -ea -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath "/D:/Eclipse 3.6.2/eclipse/plugins/org.testng.eclipse_6.8.6.20141201_2240/lib/testng.jar;D:\XML\SpringIntegration_NIC\new_temp\bin;D:\XML\SpringIntegration\lib\SeleniumServer.jar;D:\XML\SpringIntegration\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar;D:\XML\SpringIntegration\lib\selenium-java-2.37.0.zip;D:\XML\SpringIntegration_NIC\new_temp\lib\sikuli-script.jar;D:\XML\SpringIntegration_NIC\new_temp\lib\sikuli-ide.jar;D:\XML\SpringIntegration_NIC\new_temp\build.xml" org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG -serport 28844 -d D:\XML\SpringIntegration_NIC\new_temp\test-output D:\XML\SpringIntegration_NIC\new_temp\TestNG_parallel.xml
```

This is command how eclipse is giving while running from the eclipse. I have tried but some time its running and most of the time not running.

Comment: no one can able to give answer?

Comment: what's happening when you try to run it as docs say? http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng

Comment: not running actual test cases only aftersuite and before suite is running.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to the directory of your project using command line. Set a project path like this:

`C:\projects\Selenium_Project set ProjectPath = C:\projects\Selenium_Project`

2. Create a classpath which should point to the seleniu/testng class files and jar files.

`C:\projects\Selenium_Project set classpath = %ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\Lib\*`

Where \bin points to class files and \Lib points to jar files, if you have kept jar files in other folder then point to that folder only.

3. Execute java command to run

`C:\projects\Selenium_Project java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\TestXml.xml`

**Above solution will work if you are using Eclipse IDE**

Comment: Yes its running but not whole suite test cases, only after and before suites are running

Comment: check your testxml, does it contain class definitions?

Comment: for more details regarding my issue can you please check ?           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765332/testng-testcases-not-running-its-skipping

Answer (score 0):

Please run testNg XML using following :

```
C:\TestNG_WORKSPACE>java -cp "C:\TestNG_WORKSPACE" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```